# Wordpress version of jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hi i am newbie to wordpress i have a perhaps silly question:

I have in my functions.php enqued a version of jquery like this:

```
  wp_register_script('jquery2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js', false,  '1.2.6');
 //Begin enqueuing
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery2');
```

That this mean that i am using version 1.2.6 for everything in my wordpress site and the newer version, i think 1.8 that comes with wordpress is not active?

Do i have to use the 1.2.6 version of code for everything or only for the plugin that needs it and for the rest i can use 1.8 mark up??

I hope someone can explain me this in a deep way with easy english, i am spanish.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_enqueue_script()` function includes the script if it hasn't already been included, and safely handles dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer **swapnesh**, but please could you answer my question? Do i have to use 1.2.6 mark up, or 1.8 mark up after enqueing 1.2.6 version in functions? Note that i am enqueing this 1.2.6 version only for a jquery plugin i have implemented, but the thing is that coding with 1.8 mark up doesn´t give me the expected and i thought perhaps the 1.2.6 version was confusing wordpress or something ?¿. Thank you again.

Comment: @JoseLo use 1.2.6 version of code for the plugin that needs it

Comment: thank you again, i then have to use the 1.2.6 version for the plugin that needs it and 1.8(or last) for the rest of things in Wordpress. Is this correct?